Counting ways to fill the cells of an $n\times n$ table with $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, such that all four numbers appear in each $2\times2$ part?

A $n\times n$ table is given. $1$, $2$, $3$, or $4$ are written in each cell. All four numbers are written in each $2\times 2$ part of the board. How many such tables are there?

First, I thought it is one of those easy ones where you just say once we choose one $2\times 2$ square we are done because there is only one way to fill up the rest of the board. It is not, if you try $n=3$ you see that there is more than one way. I'm stumped on this and I really don't know what to do.
Edit: If it's confusing, the problem states that in every $2$ by $2$ part of the board you can find all of the numbers $1,2,3,4$
Edit 2: Oh, I forgot. I found this problem in one of my old olympiad preparation problems. You see, I'm still young and competing in international contests, and this problem I really don't want to do to be honest, I spent probably 5 minutes trying to solve it, so I thought it could be a nice puzzle for you guys.

I think if you place the first 22 matrix, say:
$\begin{matrix}
1 & 2 \
3 & 4
\end{matrix}$
then all the other 22 matrices are of the same pattern, thus the answer should be the number of ways to rearrange the 2*2 matrix, which is 4!=24

Hint to get you started (I don't know whether it leads to a solution). Once you fill the upper left $2 \times 2$ block (how many ways?) there are two ways to fill each domino below that block. Continue down the left edge (how many ways?). The think about vertical dominos to the right of the top left block.

If one 2 by 2 square has been filled clockwise as 1234 can other squares also have 1234 clockwise, or can each 2 by 2 square have any configuration which could be same or different from others ?

@Chessplayer, unfortuntaley, that is not the case. There are more ways. They don't have to be the same pattern if you play around a bit. I thougth the same

@trueblueanil They don't have to have the same configuration. Also, it is worth mentioning that 2 by 2 squares DO overlap,  so that means in every 2 by 2 square the condition holds, not just in the 2 by 2 grid.

Why is that?
For example, if we do it clockwise. I.e
$\begin{matrix}
1 &2 \
4 &3
\end{matrix}$
Thus we have to place the continuation of the first row as 4 and then 3, we can not do it 3 and then 4, because then we would have the middle 2*2 matrix, not having 1,2,3,4. I.e
$\begin{matrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \
4 & 3 & 1 & 2 \
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots
\end{matrix}$

You see you have 3,3,2,1 in one 2 by 2 square, that is not allowed

It needs to hold in EVERY 2 by 2 square

@Peter
That is what I'm saying, and that is why you can rearrange it only by rearranging the first 22 submatrix because all the other 22 submatrices will be automatically chosen

Thanks @Chessplayer for making a diagram, I stole the explanation a bit from you

I'm sorry. I wrote it without even finishing reading. You're right

@Chessplayer $\begin{matrix} 1 & 2 & 1 & 3 \ 4 & 3 & 4 & 2 \  \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots  \end{matrix}$

There are $4!(2^{n-1}-1)$ possible tables. The factor of $4!$ obviously comes from the fact that if you have a valid arrangement, then any permutation of the digits is also valid. We will ignore this and fix the top-left-most section of the table as $\begin{smallmatrix}1 & 2\\ 3 & 4\end{smallmatrix}$ instead.

First focus on the first two columns. To fulfill the requirement for all the squares in those columns, the third row has to start with $1,2$ or $2,1$, the fourth with $3,4$ or $4,3$, and so on. For now, assume that these two columns don't follow the completely regular pattern where each row starts $1,2$ or $3,4$. We have two choices for each of the remaining $n-2$ rows, minus the regular one, for a total of $2^{n-2}-1$ possible arrangements we are considering at the moment. We will prove that each one uniquely determines the entire table.
First, it is certainly possible to complete the table. Simply keep alternating between $1$ and $2$ in the odd rows, and $3$ and $4$ in the even rows. So we have to show now that there is at most one way to fill the square. Focus on the first deviation from the regular pattern:
$$\begin{matrix}1&2&?\\3&4&?\\2&\color{red}1\end{matrix}$$ (If the first deviation happens at an even row, simply swap $1\leftrightarrow3,2\leftrightarrow4$ everywhere.) One of the two question marks has to be a $1$, but because of the red $1$, it can't be the bottom one. Therefore we have placed a digit in the third column. As soon as this happens, the rest of the column is forced: The digits directly above and below the new digit are the last ones in a square, and therefore have only one option. This propagates through the entire third column. But now the second and third column look exactly like the first and second, just with $1$ swapped with $2$, and $3$ swapped with $4$. So repeat the argument to prove that there is only one way to fill the entire square.

Hence we found $2^{n-2}-1$ possible arrangements so far. We can apply the exact same argument for the first two rows instead of the first two columns for an additional $2^{n-2}-1$ combinations. There is no danger of double-counting: In the above section the first row consisted only of $1$s and $2$s, while now there is at least one $3$ or $4$ in the first row, since we didn't consider the completely regular pattern.
What remains is exactly that: The case where both the first two rows and the first two columns are repeated blocks of $\begin{smallmatrix}1 & 2\\ 3 & 4\end{smallmatrix}$. But this forces the digit in row $3$, column $3$ to be a $1$, since it is the last missing digit of a square. As before, this forces the entire third row and third column, and so on. Thus in this case the only possibility is the completely periodic table.
In total, we have therefore found $$2\cdot(2^{n-2}-1)+1=2^{n-1}-1$$ valid arrangements.

For any MathJax wizard reading this: I'd love to draw a square around the top-right four entries in the displayed matrix. Is there an easy way to do so?

Not quite what you are asking for, but: \begin{array}{|cc|c}\hline1&2&?\3&4&?\\hline2&\color{red}1\end{array}


It is not, if you try =3 you see that there is more than one way.

A $3 \times 3$ table is no way to divide it into $2 \times 2$ part of the board.
So that, assuming $n$ is even, $n \times n$ table can be made up of $(n/2) \times (n/2) $ blocks of size $2 \times 2$ sub-grid of the table. Further, for each $2 \times 2$ block, there are 24 possible arrangements of the numbers 1, 2, 3, and 4.
In addition, since the table is of size $n \times n$, the table can be divided into $(n/2) \times (n/2)$ non-overlapping $2 \times 2$ blocks, the total number of such blocks in the table is $\left( \frac{n}{2} \right) \times \left( \frac{n}{2} \right) = \frac{n^2}{4}$.
Therefore, the total number of such valid tables is $24^{\frac{n^2}{4}}$.

We consider a grid 3x3, we consider any 2x2 square in this 3x3 grid ; we can consider 4 such different squares. They all overlap and contain the central piece.
